# Probabilidades en un modelo MiMIC

Tags: rstudio

queria saber si en RStudio habia un comando para realizar probabilidades, ñuego de hacer un modelo MIMIC y habiendo obtenido los coeficientes probit, Me refiero comandos como en STATA "margins" o "mfx"